# What does / mean when showed as a parameter using the help function?

Tags: python

For example:

```
>>> help(str.rsplit)
```

prompts:

```
Help on method_descriptor:

rsplit(self, /, sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
```

What does that '/' mean?